# HTML elements changing positions on browser resize

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

Why are the boxes and images moving on browser resize in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPpDOngLoX8)?

Here is my code:

```
style="width: 98pt; position: fixed; left: 112pt; bottom: 175pt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Because...

Its design is flexible.

## How to make

According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733291/652669):

> - Use percentage based widths for dimensions of your page and elements rather than pixels.
> - Use em for your font sizes rather than px or pt.
> - Try not to use images for navigation or if you do, make them expandable using the sliding doors method. Read this: [#1](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors).
> - Read up on liquid layouts: [#2](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid) or [#3](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins).

## To go further

If you want to learn more about this, I recommend this book:

[*Responsive Web Design*](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design/) by Ethan Marcotte.

[image]

Comment: What i am trying to do though as you can tell from the video is offset the sidebar left by some inches and make it fixed. is this possible with liquid layouts?

Comment: Yes of course. If you are using Bootstrap: [Fluid Grid System](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) and [Static navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

Comment: So all i am doing in bootstrap is calling the navbar styles? Would I be able to style the structure of the html to fit my needs like how i have it in the video?

Comment: This is interesting. I've never worked with a styler like this. I've figured out the logic behind it though.

Comment: Am I able to fix it to the middle, 30 degree's to the left? Do they offer perimeters for this? This is ultimately what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are attached to the bottom of its container (the body tag maybe?)

Use "top:###pt" instead of "bottom: 175pt".

I think it would be better to specify its height instead.

```
<body>

  <div style="position:fixed; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Would need to see the HTML and CSS you are using